# snake game assembly: how the body will follow the tail.

Tags: assembly, x86-16

im trying to make a snake game using assembly language and im trying to develop a loop on how the body will follow the coordinates by the head.

the question is lets say the row is 12 and the col of head is 40, then i press "d" the head should move to the left then the body should follow,

so before moving, i should copy the current coor to the variable next coordinates 
how can i copy the values of variables row and col ----> next_row and next_col, 
should i use a register

Comment: All operations involving loading and moving memory must use a register as an intermediate step. There are no direct memory-to-memory or memory-to-segments moves. Here you will want to look at the `'inc/dec` (increment/decrement) operators and perhaps `lea` (load effective address). `lea` allows an address and increment/decrement to be specified in a single instruction. There are several other functions that scan over bits, etc.. but it all boils down to an increment/decrement of some type.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of ways to achieve this, and nothing about it is specific to assembly language.

One particularly simple approach is to not think of the body segments as moving objects, but as a trail that decays. Give each cell a counter that increments each tick.

When the head of the snake enters a cell, set that cell's counter to zero.

When the counter for a given cell is greater than he snakes's length, clear that cell.

You can overload the cell's integer value to hold quite a lot of game state if you like. For example 0=empty, 1=obstacle, ... 128=snake head. Your tick logic in this case would only increment if the value was >=128.